# Get Information programmatically that can be used to uniquely identify an iOS device

Tags: ios, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I am creating an anonymous posting application which poses an obvious security issue about someone writing in a terroristic threat or bomb threat. The app is using Firebase as it's backend and requires no client account creation/login. Is there information I can store that in such event it can be useful in being able to trace back the device? I know ad id can be used to get a unique per device identifier, but will this really allow the device to be traced back? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The short answer is you can't. You can record the device IP address, but this is not guaranteed to be able to trace back to a particular device. You can record identifierForVendor for tracking/blocking purposes but the user can just re-install

Comment: Have you arrived any better solution for your use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nice of you to be worried about someone making a bomb threat.

However, leave that to the police.

Apple will be worried that your well-meaning code to identify phones of terrorists might be used by you, knowingly or not, to breach the privacy of its customers. Therefore there is no way whatsoever to identify an iOS device.